# Uploading large files using Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-vapor

I have a Laravel application (v6.x), deployed with Vapor.

I'm trying to upload a file using a form within Laravel Nova.

Nova offers multiple ways of uploading, one using their own implementation for ease of use and another where the developer has more control.

Standard code:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
              File::make('file')
                ->disk('s3')
                ->storeSize('attachment_size')->nullable()
                ->path('ID-'.$request->associatedId)
                ->putFile()
                ->hideWhenUpdating()
                ->hideFromIndex(),
        ];
    }
```

And "taking control":

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
              File::make('file')
              ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
                // I think i can do whatever i want here.

                  return [
                      'file' => $request->file->store('/ITEM-'.$request->associatedId, 's3'),
                      'attachment_size' => $request->file->getSize(),
                  ];
              }),
         ];
    }
```

Both of these work, as long as the file is about ~3MB or less. However, i will need to upload files that are roughly 20~200 MB in size.

Whenever i try to submit the form, all the information gets stored into the database, and no error is displayed. Sadly, the file field is not filled and no upload took place.

What do i need to do to make large file uploads in Laravel nova possible?

Comment: It's probably a webserver configuration / php configuration problem. https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php.ini-directives/php-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: So far i have only been able to find the option to set the PHP version, not adjust any php settings directly. Could there be any other way to upload large files?

Comment: Maybe using S3 as a workaround?

Comment: @onlineThomas The file will be sent to S3 and stored. That is correct. the file however needs to be posted along with some other information. This will be done trough Nova's `File::make('file')` function.

Comment: @onlineThomas i have tested my local project with an increased limit. It seems to work! So all i need to figure out now is how to change the PHP settings of a Laravel app using Vapor.

Comment: How about ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M'); in code, you can place it in the boot of appserviceprovider

Comment: @onlineThomas Thank you, i tried it, but sadly it didnt work. I did come across something else. which is this [link](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/storage.html#file-uploads). I'm hoping to combine it with this  [link](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/fields.html). In this way i wont be forced to change php settings.  This however offers its own issues which im trying to resolve. I won't post those here to prevent watering down the issue. The solution i will describe.

Comment: @user1692823 So what's the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try **VaporImage/VaporFile** (Laravel\Nova\Fields\VaporImage) instead of **File/Image**

This is my code:

```
return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Name')->sortable(),
        Text::make('Original Filename')->readonly()->exceptOnForms(),
        Text::make('Content Type')->readonly()->exceptOnForms(),
        Text::make('Size')->readonly()->exceptOnForms(),
        Text::make('path')->readonly()->onlyOnDetail(),
        DateTime::make('Approved At')->sortable()->exceptOnForms(),
        VaporImage::make('Path')
            ->path('/assets')
            ->storeOriginalName('original_filename')
            ->storeOriginalSize('size')
            ->storeOriginalMimeType('content_type'),
    ];
```

Functions such as **storeOriginalSize** and **storeOriginalMimeType** doesn't exists in VaporImage class, thats why I created my own VaporImage class and extended Laravel's VaporImage.

Here is my own VaporImage class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Core;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\VaporImage as NovaVaporImage;

class VaporImage extends NovaVaporImage
{
 /**
  * The column where the file's original size should be stored.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 public $size;

 /**
  * The column where the file's original mimeType should be stored.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 public $mimeType;

 /**
  * Specify the column where the file's original size should be stored.
  *
  * @param  string  $column
  * @return $this
  */
 public function storeOriginalSize($column)
 {
     $this->size = $column;

     return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Specify the column where the file's original mimeType should be stored.
  *
  * @param  string  $column
  * @return $this
  */
 public function storeOriginalMimeType($column)
 {
     $this->mimeType = $column;

     return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Merge the specified extra file information columns into the storable attributes.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  array  $attributes
  * @return array
  */
 protected function mergeExtraStorageColumns($request, array $attributes)
 {
     if ($this->originalNameColumn) {
         $attributes[$this->originalNameColumn] = $request->input($this->attribute);
     }

     if ($this->size) {
         $attributes[$this->size] = Storage::size($request->input('vaporFile')['key']);
     }

     if ($this->mimeType) {
         $attributes[$this->mimeType] = Storage::mimeType($request->input('vaporFile')['key']);
     }

     return $attributes;
}
```